# In Postgresql, is there a way to reuse logic among several views?

Tags: sql, postgresql, view

Let's say I have several different tables that don't have a relationship to each other. I want to create a view of each table, using tedious case-when logic that needs to be updated fairly routinely. It's a pain to update the logic in each view every time.

There are two ways I can think of approaching this. 
1) Write a script that will regenerate all views by building a query everytime my logic changes.
2) Hard code the case-when logic into a table and have it join the other tables in their respective views. I would only have to focus on updating the table.

I'm wondering if there's a simpler way that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Creating a user-defined function is one option.  There may be others, if you provide a (perhaps simplified) example of what you want to do.

Comment: Put the snippet in a view, and join that to the other views or tables?  And: please **add some code** to the question.